# Problem with calling function in componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am quite new in React.js and I have trouble with assigning my state through a static function call from another class. This code:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.setState(() => ({ movies: MovieService.getMovies() }));
}
```

Does not set my state. I believe the problem lies in my usage of the asynchronous function since if I use `console.log(MovieService.getMovies())`, It shows `Promise {<pending>}`. However, I am still confused on how to fix this, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code will be setting the `movies` field of your state to a Promise object representing the pending promise returned from the call to `MovieService.getMovies()`

Try making the following adjustment to your code to resolve the issue, by first resolving the promise and then assigning the result to your components state:

```
componentDidMount() {

    MovieService.getMovies().then((movies) => {

        this.setState({ movies: movies });
    })
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
componentDidMount() {
    MovieService.getMovies().then(moviesList => {
        this.setState({ movies: moviesList }));
    })
}
```

Assuming `getMovies` returns a list of movies, you need to wait for the promise it returns to fulfil and then assign the value to your state

Comment: This answer is syntactically incorrect on this line: `this.setState(movies: moviesList }));`

Comment: Thanks @Dacre, fixed